# Get items that are not located between two dates

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

```
SELECT tabCacamba.CodCac, tabPrestadores.CodPre, tabregcac.dtini, tabregcac.dtfim
FROM tabPrestadores INNER JOIN (tabCacamba INNER JOIN tabregcac ON tabCacamba.CodCac = tabregcac.codcac
FROM tabPrestadores INNER JOIN (tabCacamba INNER JOIN tabregcac ON tabCacamba.CodCac = tabregcac.codcac) ON tabPrestadores.CodPre = tabCacamba.Prestador
WHERE (((tabCacamba.CodCac) Not In (Select tabCacamba.CodCac FROM tabCacamba WHERE [Initial Date] between tabRegCac.dtIni and tabRegCac.dtFim)));
```

this code is not working, we need to select all the "cacambas" that are avalible, so for that we are using the not in function on access but the data keep getting duplicated

Comment: This is a purely SQL question.  The fact that you are executing the SQL from a VB.NET application is irrelevant tot he question.  I have modified the tags accordingly.

Comment: Sample data and the output you'd like to get from that data would help, especially with the SQL you've posted.

Comment: Duplication would be expected if including many-to-many related tables in query. There may even be something else going on in such complicated multiple joins and nesting. The date criteria is not really complicated and difficult but all those joins are confusing.

Comment: Your code is not syntactically correct.  Queries do not  have two `FROM` clauses.

Comment: You seem to have an incorrect sql Line2 , which is later fixed as Line3.  Please remove the 2nd line